# Convert dates into numbers

Tags: r

I need your support while working with dates.
While importing an .xls file, the column of dates was correctly converted into numbers by R. Unfortunately some dates are still there in the format: dd/mm/yyyy or d/mm/yyyy or dd/mm/yy. Probably this results from different settings of different os. I don't know. Is there a way to manage this?

Thank you in advance

> ```
>  my_data <- read_excel("my_file.xls")
> ```

> ```
> born_date     
>  18520            
>  30859                     
>  16/04/1972       
>  26612            
>  30291            
>  24435 
> 11/02/1964       
> 26/09/1971       
>  18427            
>  23688
> ```

> Original_dates
> 14/9/1950
> 26/6/1984
> 16/04/1972
> 9/11/1972
> 6/12/1982
> 24/11/1966
> 11/02/1964
> 26/09/1971
> 13/6/1950

Comment: Probably. Can you post a 5-10 rows of sample data illustrating the problem? Can you post the code you used to import the xlsx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way how we could solve it:
First we define the numeric values only by exlcuden those containing the string `/`.
Then we use `excel_numeric_to_date` function from `janitor` package.
Finally with `coalesce` we combine both:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(x = ifelse(str_detect(born_date, '\\/'), NA_real_, born_date),
         x = excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(as.character(x)), date_system = "modern"),
         born_date = dmy(born_date)) %>% 
  mutate(born_date = coalesce(born_date, x), .keep="unused")
```

```
    born_date
1  1950-09-14
2  1984-06-26
3  1972-04-16
4  1972-11-09
5  1982-12-06
6  1966-11-24
7  1964-02-11
8  1971-09-26
9  1950-06-13
10 1964-11-07
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(born_date = c("18520", "30859", "16/04/1972", 
"26612", "30291", "24435", "11/02/1964", "26/09/1971", "18427", 
"23688")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thank you TraJae! Finally I got it! I found that it is possible to specify detectDates = TRUE while reading xlsx so that the issue is only for dates like /../../ you helped me to solve! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

**1)** This translates the two types of dates.  Each returns an NA for those elements not of that type. Then we use coalesce to combine them.  This only needs dplyr and no warnings are produced.

```
library(dplyr)

my_data %>%
 mutate(born_date = coalesce(
  as.Date(born_date, "%d/%m/%Y"), 
  as.Date(as.numeric(ifelse(grepl("/",born_date), NA, born_date)), "1899-12-30"))
  )
##     born_date
## 1  1950-09-14
## 2  1984-06-26
## 3  1972-04-16
## 4  1972-11-09
## 5  1982-12-06
## 6  1966-11-24
## 7  1964-02-11
## 8  1971-09-26
## 9  1950-06-13
## 10 1964-11-07
```

**2)** Here is a base R version.

```
my_data |>
 transform(born_date = pmin(na.rm = TRUE,
  as.Date(born_date, "%d/%m/%Y"), 
  as.Date(as.numeric(ifelse(grepl("/",born_date), NA, born_date)), "1899-12-30"))
 )
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form.

```
my_data <-
structure(list(born_date = c("18520", "30859", "16/04/1972", 
"26612", "30291", "24435", "11/02/1964", "26/09/1971", "18427", 
"23688")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```